# Como implementar o algoritmo da Teoria dos seis graus de separação?

Tags: c#, algoritmo

### O que é?

[Teoria](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_dos_seis_graus_de_separa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) de que, no mundo, são necessários no máximo seis laços de amizade para que duas pessoas quaisquer estejam ligadas.

### Pergunta:

Estou a algum tempo tentando implementar esse algoritmo, mas não consigo imaginar como eu faria as ligações, quero fazer como forma de **[PoC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prova_de_conceito)**, para entender melhor como funciona um dos  algoritmos que as redes sociais utilizam.

Comment: Sua dúvida é como levantar os dados necessários para tal verificação, ou como analisar dados já existentes? (ex.: você tem um grafo de pessoas e relações de amizade, e quer achar o ["maior caminho mínimo entre quaisquer vértices"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths))

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu pensei no seguinte: Objeto Pessoa tem uma Lista de Pessoa que no caso é sua rede de amigos. Minha dúvida é o seguinte: Tenho a Pessoa "João", como vou chegar no "João" através do "Pedro" que possui amigos em comum com ele? Só que para chegar no "Pedro" eu tenho que andar em toda a Lista de Amigos dele e dos Amigos dele também e assim por diante. Nessa parte que me deu uma trava que não consigo mais avançar. Queria fazer o seguinte: Pedro->Ana->Jorge->Rafael->João (Quais pessoas eu tive que passar para encontrar João, o grau seria mais fácil calcular a partir daí).

Comment: Ou seja, a dúvida é no algoritmo mesmo. Veja a minha resposta. Sua ideia - escolher "João" e "Pedro" e então calcular a distância entre eles - funciona, mas é ineficiente: você teria que fazer isso para cada par (i.e. `O(V^2)`) sendo que cada verificação teria que percorrer todas as relações de amizade (`O(E)` - total: `O(V^2 * E)`). Se em vez disso você fixar "João" e calcular a distância dele pra todo mundo de uma vez só você consegue reduzir isso pra `O(V*E)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse problema não só pode ser resolvido com algoritmos clássicos da [teoria dos grafos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_dos_grafos), como existem implementações já prontas em diversas linguagens, incluindo C#.

Em primeiro lugar, considere que sua massa de dados contém pessoas e relacionamentos entre pessoas. Independentemente de como isso está representado ([seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13811/como-implementar-o-algoritmo-da-teoria-dos-seis-graus-de-separacao#comment24197_13811) sugere uma [lista de adjacência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_adjac%C3%AAncia)), isso forma um **grafo** onde cada pessoa é um **vértice** e a relação "fulano é amigo de beltrano" constitui uma **aresta**. Como queremos simplesmente a "distância" entre duas pessoas, pode-se considerar que esse grafo não possui "pesos" (i.e. você ou é amigo de fulano ou não é) e - embora isso não seja relevante nesse caso - a relação de amizade é comutativa (se A é amigo de B, então B é amigo de A). O resultado então é um **grafo não direcionado sem pesos**.

A proposição a ser testada:

> São necessários no máximo seis laços de amizade para que duas pessoas quaisquer estejam ligadas.

na linguagem dos grafos é equivalente a:

> Para todo vértice A e todo vértice B, o menor caminho entre A e B é menor ou igual a 6.

Ou seja, testar a proposição se resume a solucionar o [problema do menor caminho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) para todo vértice V, e testar se todos os caminhos resultantes são menores ou iguais a 6. O algoritmo mais simples e mais eficiente para esse tipo de grafo é a [busca em largura](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_largura).

No seu caso particular:

1. Crie uma matriz Pessoa x Pessoa onde todo elemento é "não visitado";
2. Para cada Pessoa `P`:

   1. Crie uma [fila (FIFO)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) - em C#, [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) - e coloque `P` nela, com distância zero;
   2. Considere o número de pessoas não visitadas `NV` como o número total de pessoas;
   3. Enquanto `NV > 0`:

      1. Se a fila estiver vazia, pare - há pessoas que não estão ligadas de nenhuma forma.
      2. Retire a primeira pessoa `X` da fila, e verifique sua distância a `P`;
      3. Se `X` já tiver sido visitada antes, volte ao início do loop (há um caminho mais curto entre `P` e `X`, já descoberto);
      4. Senão, atribua a distância de P a X (e de X a P), e decremente `NV`;

         - Aqui você já pode testar se a distância é ou não maior que `6`.
      5. Para cada amigo de `X`, adicione-o na fila, com a distância incrementada em `1`.

Uma pesquisa por "c sharp breadth first" retorna vários resultados (como [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111694/520779)), mas pela particularidade desse seu teste, eu sugiro tentar implementar conforme o algoritmo descrito acima (talvez usando o código linkado como referência) - já que pode-se fazer algumas otimizações em relação ao problema mais geral (parar quando todos os vértices já foram visitados, parar quando a distância for maior que `6`, etc).